# Video Player that lets you play multiple videos after highlighting them in a folder?

Tags: video, windows-10

Before I switched to Windows 10, I could highlight a bunch of videos and right click then add to media player playlist and it would play all the files in succession. That no longer appears.

0. In VLC, I tried the Media -> Open Multiple Files. It does not play the videos in the same order that they were in inside of the folder.
1. What is the best software for what I described in *?
2. This seems like something that should have been easily searchable. I tried searching "play videos one after another" and "play playlist"- those don't seem to be the most intelligent things to search
   Here's an answer from 2008 though not exactly what I'm looking for and has a pretty sketchy looking link from jetaudio
   http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/283623-video-player-to-play-movie-one-after-the-other

What's something more modern?

Comment: Have you tried MPC-HC? Download it and check `View -> Playlist`. Honestly, I haven't tried making playlist using this software, but It is still the best media player in my opinion. I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: I clicked View Playlist and see a white bar on the bottom of MPC HC. What do I do next? I would like to highlight a bunch of files in a folder and play them in order and I don't see the connection

Comment: Select the files you want and drag them into the white bar. You can change the order however you want. You can also select the files and open them together ( `Right Click -> Open` ) and they will appear in the bar.